# Is it possible to hide a Visualforce Tab in Lightning but Visible in Classic

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have created an App in Salesforce and added a Visualforce Tabs and Lightning Component Tabs to it.

Is it possible with just the one App to hide the Visualforce Tabs from showing within Lightning mode but visible within Classic mode?

The reason for this question, Is I have Visualforce Tab which reference a Lightning Component and this Lightning Component is also a Lightning Component Tab for Lightning, meaning I have two tabs showing in Lightning mode with the same name.

Ideally I don't want to remove the Light Component Tab and just use the Visualforce Tab that references the Lightning Component in Lightning mode.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You can uncheck available for lightning experience and SF1 for your vf and get rid of duplicates

[image]

Comment: I have this option unchecked, yet still the tab is visible in Lightning Experience?

Comment: Yup, same situation here with me. Did you figure it out anyways? @ChrisCiszak

Comment: I had tried the same but still the tab is visible in lightning as well.